# Parse: How to share a relation between two Parse objects?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Parse Object `Community` that has a relation `people` which is basically a list of people (`User` object) in that community. 
I've another Parse Object `Role` that also has a relation `people`. 
I want both these `people` relations to be identical, so that whenever I add/remove a `User`to the `people` relation in `Community` it is automatically added/removed from the `people` relation in `Role`.

Comment: Get rid of Community. Its superflous in your spec. Just use the _Role in ACL in other classes and you will achieve the resjlt u want with no Community object